# Replace HTML tags through regular expression using dart language

Tags: regex, dart

How should we replace <br /> html tags with line feed '\n' using RegExp in dart?

**Input:**

```
one<br />two<br />three
```

**Output:**

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? A simple search-and-replace action seems to be sufficient. Unless you need to handle variable amounts of whitespace, then `<br\s*/>` would be a useful search regex.

Comment: text can contain <br/> or <br />

Comment: As I wrote, then `<br\s*/>` should work.

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: What syntax are you using to construct the regex in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
final _brRe = RegExp(r"<br\s*/>");
String replaceBreaks(String input) =>
    input.replaceAll(_brRe, "\n");
```

You create a RegExp using the `RegExp` constructor, remembering to always use a *raw* string literal, so you don't need to double-escape backslashes.

Then you just use `String.replaceAll` to replace all substrings matched by the RegExp with a newline.

Comment: With this, problem is middle one is getting missed out.... Input: One<br />two<br />three. Output: one\nthree

Comment: When I run the code, it correctly replaces both `<br />`s with newlines, and retains the `One`, `two` and `three` strings. Check: https://dartpad.dev/?id=a6b1cb1898e0aaa38ddb78a226790a34 . You must be doing something differently.
Are you, by any chance, changing the regexp to `r"<br.*/>"`?